# Горячие клавиши чтобы закрывать вкладки?

Tags: android-studio

Я извиняюсь за общий вопрос, но у меня не получилось найти как в студии закрывать вкладки...

Когда работаю с проектом у меня в настройках стоит отображать вкладки до 25 штук, но когда я заканчиваю работать над какой то задачей, то приходиться тянуться к каждому крестику и закрывать эти вкладки(чтоб не мазолили глаза).

У меня Ubuntu когда я работаю в хроме комбинация клавиш `Ctrl + W` закрывает текущую вкладку а комбинация `Ctrl + Shift + W` закрывает все доступные вкладки.

Есть ли такая возможность в студии?

Comment: Горячие клавиши на закрытие вкладки\всех вкладок?

Comment: @pavlofff да они

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В дефолтных настройках <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> - закрыть текущий таб (Лучше другие кнопки забиндить, т.к. может кидать на 4й стол). Хоткеи на закрытие всех табов не включены, то есть надо самому забиндить:

1. Нужно зайти в настройки (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd>`)
2. Key map
3. В строке поиска вводим `Close`, и в подменю `Editor Tabs` (если не использовать поиск, то `Main menu -> Window -> Editor Tabs`) будут нужные пункты `Close, Close All` (ну а также три других действия с закрытием табов.

[image: Android Studio keymap]

Answer (score 1):

В Windows закрыть текущую вкладку <kbd>CTRL + F4</kbd>, на закрыть все вкладки по дефолту не назначено, но вы можете назначить сами, проследовав: *File -> Setings.. -> Keymap*

[image: scrn]

Здесь же вы можете установить свои сочетания клавиш и узнать, какие еще есть горячие клавиши.

Для быстрого поиска горячих клавиш они подписаны рядом с теми пунктами меню, которое действие будет выполняться при их нажатии/ Так при правом клике мышью на вкладке мы увидим действия, доступные для этой вкладки и прикрепленные горячие клавиши:

[image: scrn]